# CBP Receipt - H1 Visa Interview

Tags: customs-and-immigration, h1b-visas, fines, interview

I had my visa interview today and the visa interviewer asked me for a CBP receipt which I received in 2012. I had carried some food items and received a $300 ticket at the US port of entry. How do I get that receipt now, as I have lost it? Can anyone please help me with that?